# Is any enabling and disable touch Events

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to enable and disable touch Events.

I got two view's - `UIImageView` and `UIView`. I want to enable touch on the `UIImageView` but not on the `UIView`.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 7):

UIView has a property called [`userInteractionEnabled`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/userInteractionEnabled) which you can set to NO to disable touch events on that view.

Answer (score -3):

i think it is not possible to do like that.because apple does not provide an API for that....

Comment: Look at the below answer. view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;